# correct usage of generics while creating hashmap

Tags: java, generics

I have a hashMap where key is String and value could be Integer or long .
Now in a method I am creating this HashMap and passing into other method something like

```
methodA(long a,Integer b)

{
Map<String,? super Number> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("key1",a);
hm.put("key2",b);

invokeMethodC(hm);
}

invokeMethodC(Map<String, ?> uriVariables)
{
....
}
```

Just wanted to know whether i have used correct generics while creating hashMap object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use extends/super as you will not be able to put elements in a Map.It will give a compilation error

```
Map<String, Number> uriVariables = = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: I have used super not extends

Comment: Yep just saw that .Corrected my answer.Have a look a this link for getting more info about adding elements with lower bounded wildcards http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html

Answer (score 1):

`Map<String,? super Number>` will return Object on get(). It is better to use `Map<String, Number>` then put() will accept Long and Integer and get() will return Number